# Airflow export schema only from PostgreSQL to bigquery

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery, airflow

In airflow, we can export databases like postgres, MySQL and etc to GCS. they have an option called schema file where the SCHEMA of the source table will be exported as a JSON file, and we can use it for creating the table on bigquery.

But unfortunately, we can export the schema file with `select * from table;` (or we can reduce the rows with `select * from table limit 1`). It will upload both the data and the schema files.

Is there a way to export only the schema file without data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to pull the schema/metadata/columns from your table.

For example:

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
 `bigquery-public-data`.census_bureau_usa.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
 table_name="population_by_zip_2010"
```

[image]

See [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#columns_view).

Comment: Yes, (i think you posted this from BQ, but the same solution will work for Postgres as well) Im looking for zero code changes :) if any possibilities from existing operators.